# TeamCity set buildType parameter with rest API

Tags: rest, teamcity

I want to set a build parameter with rest api.Then i make some research and find these documents&articles.

- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/rest-api.html#RESTAPI-TypedParametersSpecification
- https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/REST+API#RESTAPI-TypedParametersSpecification

And i do http call as they documented above.

*Request for getting parameter*

```
GET
Accept */*
http://myTeamCityServer/app/rest/buildTypes/id:myBuildTypeId/parameters/myParameter/value
```

*Response*

```
200
myValue
```

*Request for setting parameter*

```
PUT
http://myTeamCityServer/app/rest/buildTypes/id:myBuildTypeId/parameters/myParameter/value
--data yourValue
```

*Response*

```
200
myValue
```

So nothing is changed. **PUT** response is **same** as **GET** response. It is also return 200 OK. How can i be able to set build parameter ?  Where did i do wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Trial and error learning*; 
i make `PUT` request through `https`. And the response is:

`403 Forbidden: Responding with 403 status code due to failed CSRF check: no "Origin" header is present and no authentication provided with the request, consider adding "Origin: http://myTeamCityServer" header.`

Respect to this response i put `Origin` header to request and request is worked as expected.

In addition adding `X-CSRF-Token` header is solved the problem.